# Growing my 1st Morninga Tree- Slow Growth Curling Leaves

Tags: plant-health

[image]

Hi everyone. First I'll admit I'm a beginner gardener in the harshest of gardening areas- I'm in the Mojave Desert of So-Cal. I bought 30 moringa seeds and got one to grow.

I started in a large pot, a little early, it was still a bit cold but was indoors so I kept her warm as best I could. I recently went ahead and transplanted her to her spot. I used steer and chicken manure with regular potting soil and of course, the sand we live on which has literally no value. I water her in the morning and afternoon, she gets full sunshine all day. The temperatures are between 80-90ish in the upper 50s to 60s at night. I kinda thought she was slow growing because it was cold when I started this whole thing but now I'm now about 3 months in, about a month in the actual soil, well maybe 3 weeks, and I'm thinking she outta be bigger. Her lower leaves were turning yellow so I pulled those off and I'm attaching a picture of how she looks now. What am I doing wrong?

I wanted to grow moringa trees for shade. We do get a bit of wind but where I planted her she's somewhat protected from the wind.